# mongodb: Update a position of an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a houses collections in which each house has an array of rooms, and each room has a field called 'beds' which indicates the number of beds in the room. We have added a bed in those rooms that already had at least one. So I want to update this information in the DB.

I try to create a script in the console directly, to make it fast. But I can't manage to create that $set field *rooms['+roomNum+'].beds*  dynamically, it gives a parsing error.

```
 db.houses.find().forEach(
        function(house){ 
            var id = house._id;
            var roomNum = 0;
            house.rooms.forEach(function(room){
                if (room.beds!= null && room.beds!=0){
                    db.houses.update({_id:id},{'$set':{'rooms['+roomNum+'].beds':room.beds+1}});
                }
                roomNum++;
            });     
        }
    )
```

I tried other ways like putting it in a variable, but then it considers the name of the variable as the name of the field. I tried also *rooms[roomNum]['beds']* but it does not work neither